# Как в eclipse включить jar либу в результирующий apk?

Tags: ant, eclipse, android, jar

Имеется библиотека с откомпилированными *.class в виде jar. В Project -> Java Build Path -> Libraries подключаю её - apk собирается.
Во время работы приложения обращения к классам вываливаются в NoClassDefFoundError.
Можно ли решить проблему без ant и подобного (без копирования class в результирующий apk)?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение: нужно скомпилить библиотеку под java 1.6 вместо 1.7 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316508/1395958)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте папку libs и туда добавьте эту библиотеку (не в папке res *(тут была ошибка)*)

И библиотеку лучше переподключить оттуда же

Comment: /res/libs/*.jar?

Comment: да, именно
иначе вашей библиотеки вообще не оказывается в apk

Comment: aapt ругается (invalid resource directory name), да и про такие ресурсы я не слышал ранее и гайд про них не знает (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

Comment: @wapmorgan Наверно я не с потолка взял эту информацию, а то что у вас было скомпилено под 1.7 я не телепат

[пруф][1] (правда я слегка ошибся, папка libs не в res)
 [1]:http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html